# Warning: Unknown: SAFE MODE Restriction in effect. The script whose uid is 10014 is not allowed to access / owned by uid 0 in Unknown on line 0

Tags: php, .htaccess, permissions, file-permissions, php-safe-mode

I have a site on one of those low cost web hosts and I've been having some problems with some files generating the following error:

**Warning:  Unknown: SAFE MODE Restriction in effect.  The script whose uid is 10014 is not allowed to access / owned by uid 0 in Unknown on line 0**

I've placed a **php.ini** file at root level with the following:

safe_mode = off

I've also placed the following in a **.htaccess** file at root level:

php_flag safe_mode off

If I run a phpinfo() script, I do show that safe_mode is off.  I'm still getting the error above on some files, though.  One of those errors is in the main javascript file, so as you can imagine, that's quite a bummer.

Permissions on the JS folder/file are **755**

Server is running **PHP Version 5.2.17**

I'm also getting some "Image corrupt or truncated:" errors in Firebug.  As you can imagine, those are pretty annoying as well as that means not all my images are loading.

I've cleared my cache/reloaded in several browsers, but still have issues on the site.

I didn't used to get this problem and my web host isn't the greatest at responding or even giving information.  I have a suspicion they just change things and don't even bother sending out notice of what/when they're making changes (incredibly annoying).  I've had other issues in the past with the site working fine, then just start having issues.  Again, low cost web host so not a big surprise, right?

Anyways, anyone have any ideas how I can resolve the safe mode error above?

Comment: at root level? not f. ex. in /etc? use `phpinfo();` to see your main `php.ini`.

Comment: Or `chown` your files (change owner) to the user which has uid 10014.

Comment: ok when you see this error?

Comment: Don't have access to /etc.  phpinfo() shows me safe mode is off as well.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that your system admins will allow you to disable PHP Safe Mode due to security reansons. I think you have only two solutions:
- Put the files you want to access in your script's directory or a child directory.
- Move to a different hosting provider.
This configuration can also be tricky with other PHP features such as mail() function.

Comment: I think you are right.+1 to you but my answer could be also a nice try for that what do you think?

Comment: They actually do.  I can toggle my safe_mode value in my php.ini file (which I place at root level in httpdocs), reload my phpinfo() file and see my safe_mode value say on or off.  I also commented out my safe_mode line in my .htaccess file so my php.ini file is the only file in play here.